# How to open multiple windows of the same file in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-import

I have a simple application in python. When I click a button it should open up the same file multiple times. However, after two times the program won't open any more windows.

Here is my code so far for file1:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x600")

def newWin():
   import file1

button = Button(root, text="Open Window of same file", command=newWin)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

After clicking the button one time, it opens up the same file in a new window, but when I click the button in that window, it doesn't work. How do I fix this?

Comment: What about file2? Would you mind providing the code for that?

Comment: No there is no file2, I am opening file1 from file1.

Comment: Move the code in `file1` inside a function, for example `open_window()` and call that function: `import file1; file1.open_window()`.

Answer (score 1):

`import file1` will only import `file1` and execute the code inside `file1` once.  When `import file1` is called again, nothing will happen because `file1` has already been imported.

To get around this, you can put the code inside a function and call that function after importing `file1`:

```py
# file1.py
import tkinter as tk

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('600x600')

    def new_win():
        import file1
        file1.main()

    button = tk.Button(root, text='Open Window of same file', command=new_win)
    button.pack()

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

However, importing `file1` inside `file1` is not a good practice and should be avoided.

---

The above code is just a demo of fixing the import issue.  Actually you don't need to call `import file1` inside `file1`, just call `main()`:

```py
# file1.py
import tkinter as tk

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('600x600')

    button = tk.Button(root, text='Open Window of same file', command=main)
    button.pack()

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: @10Rep Fixing typos or grammar is really appreciated, but not adding your comment in other's solution.  You can put your comment as real comment.

Comment: Still doesnt work, it says file1 has no attribute 'main'. So how do I fix this?

Comment: Really? Are u able to open the file more than 2 times.

Comment: Not open the file more than one. As I said file can only be imported once using `import` statement.  I can call the `main()` multiple times.

Comment: Why is it not a good practice to import file1 inside file1?

Comment: how do I make it open multiple times?

Answer (score -1):

Your button has no command parameter, otherwise, it will do nothing.

```
button = Button(root, text="Open Window of same file", command = newWin)
```

Also, change add the `.py` extension while importing your file:

```
import file1.py
```

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to add a command, in my IDE I have the command yet it does not work. Is there another way?

Comment: Make sure you have opened the IDE in the same directory of your file1.py and use import file1.py instead of import file1

Comment: @ADITYAKUMAR The OP will not accept the answer because they said it didn't work.

Comment: @ADITYAKUMAR You shouldn't do `import file1.py`. It will pass an error after  the second iteration, stating that the package doesn't exist.

Comment: @ADITYAKUMAR I dont want to downvote but this answer is actually not correct, you just cannot import a py file by suffixing it with py, only py files can be imported using `import`, i think you should change the code asap